# Can't add device to Library - Provisioning Profiles in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-provisioning

Every time I press "New" in Organizer - Devices - Library - Provisioning Profiles I get a message:

"Your developer account needs to be updated. Please visit the Member Center. http://developer.apple.com/membercenter"

When I go there, everything is up-to-date and I nothing is indicating there I need to update anything. All my personal information are updated and also all new legal agreements are approved and read. I have admin rights.

I use Xcode 4.6.

Comment: Double-check that there aren't any new contracts/contract amendments you need to agree to. I think they're listed in the sidebar of the portal.

Comment: There are not. Furthermore, my colleague has the same profile - admin - and is able to do everything, but he has more project there. My installation of X-Code is pretty clean, so I maybe need to adjust some settings somewhere within X-Code?

Comment: OK, so the resolution for this issue is - do not have 2 developer profiles with under the same email address. Not sure how it is possible and why they have allowed that, but the error message is very misleading. Anyway, fixed now and working fine.

Comment: Can I please get a better description of you solved this? Scratching my head, cannot solve it, not sure what you mean with "2 developer profiles with under the same email address" as this team has only one person, do you mean people in the iOS Developers part of the member center?

Comment: I have somehow created 2 developer profiles under 1 and the same email address - not sure how, but I did. So check if you have only 1 developer profile under each email address you are using. Does not matter which team it is under, it seems you can not use 1 email address under more profiles under 1 X-Code.

Comment: Isnt it because you are a "Member" not "Admin" or "Agent" in your team? From App Distribution Guide: "Before a team member can launch an app on his or her device, the device needs to be registered and added to the team provisioning profile. Xcode automatically registers team agent and admin devices when needed, as described in “Launching Your App on Devices” (page 84). However, a team agent or admin must register team member devices on their behalf.
"

Answer (score 0):

Just checked it - **you need to be admin or agent to add devices**, so you need to ask your admin/agent to add the device for you or ask for becoming the admin/agent in your team. In case of further problems you should delete all your connected accounts from Xcode and readd the ones you need.

As App Distribution Guide states:

> Before a team member can launch an app on his or her device, the device needs to be registered and added to the team provisioning profile. Xcode automatically registers team agent and admin devices when needed, as described in “Launching Your App on Devices” (page 84). However, a team agent or admin must register team member devices on their behalf.

This make perfect sense as in other way the listo of devices would be not manageable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the first part of the error message

> Your developer account needs to be updated. Please visit the Member
>   Center. http://developer.apple.com/membercenter

is rightly pointing to the resolution. That is there were a couple of **Apple IDs** that I added to my **Xcode->Prefrences->Accounts** and they were no longer valid. So, deleting or updating them resolve the issue.